# tag selector doesn't show correct result in some browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm making an wysiwig editor using jquery-tagSelector.js.

(example is avaliable on http://jcesar.artelogico.com/jquery-tagselector/)

The problem is this: some browsers cannot show correct result
(I cannot show you a picture because I have to earn more than 10 reputation to post images.)

It occurs in some IE6, IE7 and IE8 but not in other IE6, IE7 and IE8. I think it is due to JavaScript version of client's computer. Is it right?

Or is there any solution to solve this problem?

you can see it in http://www.kosfan.com/home/board/default_test/write here.

Comment: http://www.kosfan.com/file/download/2f82c08f9fc60090b3aefbe0eafd8eac this is error message!

Comment: Check a lastest version - https://code.google.com/archive/p/petprojects/issues/1